# Django force null field

Tags: python, django, null

I am curious if you can force a null field in a django model. Take the following model:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

so essentially `some_field` is a required field as I have not specified `blank=True` or a default, but the question is **how would I make it null**?

My only idea is creating the object with the following:

```
FooBar(some_field__isnull=True)
```

But I do not know if this is true and cannot test it out at the moment as I am not using my own computer and would rather not have to install python and django.

## Actual reason for ever doing this

The reason someone would want to do this is more of a `get_or_create` situation. In the majority of projects, there will always be `blank=True` when there is `null=True`, so forcing it is not usually necessary. But if you need to use `get_or_create` where the field **must be null**, then you must use `some_field__isnull=True`. I have only been able to find this type of code done in a `get` and not a `create`, so I cannot tell if `FooBar.objects.get_or_create(some_field__isnull=True)` is actually valid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `None` to set a field to `NULL`:

```
foobar = FooBar(some_field=None)
```

Comment: then what is the purpose of having `__isnull`? Is it simply a redundant capability?

Comment: @RyanSaxe __isnull is field lookup: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Comment: @RyanSaxe -- `__isnull` does seem redundant for matching nulls (as you can always do `some_field=None`) but can be useful when excluding nulls i.e. `some_field__isnull=False` without having to use a Q object i.e. `~Q(some_field=None)`